# Python 3: IndexError: list index out of range while doing Knapsack Problem

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently self-learning python for a career change. While doing some exercises about 'list', I encountered  IndexError: list index out of range.

So, I am trying to build a function, that determines which product should be placed on my store's shelves. But, I also put constraints.

1. The shelve has a max capacity of 200
2. small-sized items should be placed first
3. if two or more items have the same size, the item with the highest price should be placed first

As an input for the function, I have a list of tuples "dairy_items", denoted as [(id, size, price)].

This is my code:

```
capacity=200

dairy_items=[('p1', 10, 3), ('p2', 13, 5),
            ('p3', 15, 2), ('p4', 26, 2),
            ('p5', 18, 6), ('p6', 25, 3),
            ('p7', 20, 4), ('p8', 10, 5),
            ('p9', 15, 4), ('p10', 12, 7),
            ('p11', 19, 3), ('p12', 27, 6),
            ('p13', 16, 4), ('p14', 23, 5),
            ('p15', 14, 2), ('p16', 23, 5),
            ('p17', 12, 7), ('p18', 11, 3),
            ('p19', 16, 5), ('p20', 11, 4)]

def shelving(dairy_items):
    #first: sort the list of tuples based on size: low-to-big
    items = sorted(dairy_items, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
    #second: iterate the sorted list of tuples.
    #agorithm: retrieve the first 2 elements of the sorted list 
            #then compare those two elements by applying rules/conditions as stated
                #the 'winning' element is placed to 'result' and this element is removed from 'items'. Also 'temp' list is resetted
                #do again untill shelves cannot be added anymore (capacity full and do not exceeds limit) 
    result = []
    total_price = []
    temp_capacity = []
    temp = items[:2]
    while sum(temp_capacity) < capacity:
        #add conditions: (low first) and (if size the same, highest price first)
        if (temp[0][1] == temp[1][1]) and (temp[0][2] > temp[1][2]):
            temp_capacity.append(temp[0][1])
            result.append(temp.pop(0))
            items.pop(0)
            temp.clear()
            temp = items[:2]
            total_price.append(temp[0][2])
        elif ((temp[0][1] == temp[1][1])) and (temp[0][2] < temp[1][2]):
            temp_capacity.append(temp[1][1])
            result.append(temp.pop())
            items.pop()
            temp.clear()
            temp = items[:2]
            total_price.append(temp[1][2])
        else:
            temp_capacity.append(temp[0][1])
            result.append(temp.pop(0))
            items.pop(0)
            temp.clear()
            temp = items[:2]
            total_price.append(temp[0][2])
    result = result.append(temp_capacity)
    #return a tuple with three elements: ([list of product ID to be placed in order], total occupied capacity of shelves, total prices)
    return result
```

```
c:\Users\abc\downloads\listexercise.py in <module>
----> 1 print(shelving(dairy_items))

c:\Users\abc\downloads\listexercise.py in shelving(dairy_items)
     28     while sum(temp_capacity) < capacity:
     29 
---> 30         if (temp[0][1] == temp[1][1]) and (temp[0][2] > temp[1][2]):
     31             temp_capacity.append(temp[0][1])
     32             result.append(temp2.pop(0))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

EDIT:

This is the expected result:

```
#Result should be True
print(shelving(dairy_items) == (['p8', 'p1', 'p20', 'p18', 'p10', 'p17', 'p2', 'p15', 'p9', 'p3', 'p19', 'p13', 'p5', 'p11'], 192, 60))
```

Comment: check the dimensions on `temp` - when reaching `if (temp[0][1] == temp[1][1]) and (temp[0][2] > temp[1][2]):` one of those is out of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IndexError` occured because, you had tried to append the 2nd element after popping it from `temp` because, after popping it out, there will be only one element in `temp` which can indexed with `0`.

Also I noticed a few more bugs which could hinder your program from giving the correct output and rectified them.

The following code will work efficiently...

```py
from time import time

start = time()

capacity = 200

dairy_items = [('p1', 10, 3), ('p2', 13, 5),
            ('p3', 15, 2), ('p4', 26, 2),
            ('p5', 18, 6), ('p6', 25, 3),
            ('p7', 20, 4), ('p8', 10, 5),
            ('p9', 15, 4), ('p10', 12, 7),
            ('p11', 19, 3), ('p12', 27, 6),
            ('p13', 16, 4), ('p14', 23, 5),
            ('p15', 14, 2), ('p16', 23, 5),
            ('p17', 12, 7), ('p18', 11, 3),
            ('p19', 16, 5), ('p20', 11, 4)]

def shelving(dairy_items):
    items = sorted(dairy_items, key=lambda x: x[1])
    result = ([],)
    total_price, temp_capacity = 0, 0

    while (temp_capacity+items[0][1]) < capacity:
        temp = items[:2]

        if temp[0][1] == temp[1][1]:
            if temp[0][2] > temp[1][2]:
                temp_capacity += temp[0][1]
                result[0].append(temp[0][0])
                total_price += temp[0][2]
                items.pop(0)
            elif temp[0][2] < temp[1][2]:
                temp_capacity += temp[1][1]
                result[0].append(temp[1][0])
                total_price += temp[1][2]
                items.pop(items.index(temp[1]))
            else:
                temp_capacity += temp[0][1]
                result[0].append(temp[0][0])
                total_price += temp[0][2]
                items.pop(0)
        else:
            temp_capacity += temp[0][1]
            result[0].append(temp[0][0])
            total_price += temp[0][2]
            items.pop(0)

    result += (temp_capacity, total_price)
    return result

a = shelving(dairy_items)

end = time()

print(a)

print(f"\nTime Taken : {end-start} secs")
```

Output:-

```
(['p8', 'p1', 'p20', 'p18', 'p10', 'p17', 'p2', 'p15', 'p9', 'p3', 'p19', 'p13', 'p5', 'p11'], 192, 60)

Time Taken : 3.123283386230469e-05 secs
```

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes! It is indeed more efficient and readable. I do have question: why are you using the index here ```items.pop(items.index(temp[1]))``` instead just items.pop(1) ? Any specific reason?

Comment: Nothing, its just that, I got a doubt whether the 2nd element in `temp` will be the same as the 2nd element in `items` and You're Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but the following information may be relevant:

[IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) occurs when a sequence subscript is out of range. What does this mean? Consider the following code:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
a = l[0]
```

This code does two things:

1. Define a list of 3 integers called l
2. Assigns the first element of l to a variable called a

Now, if I were to do the following:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
a = l[3]
```

I would raise an IndexError, as I'm accessing the fouth element of a three element list. Somewhere in your code, you're likely over-indexing your list. This is a good chance to learn about debugging using pdg. Throw a call to breakpoint() in your code and inspect the variables, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

ok, firstly, you should debug your code, if you print `temp` before adding `temp[1][2]` to `total_price` you would see that the last index is what causing the error, the example is here:

```
capacity=200

dairy_items=[('p1', 10, 3), ('p2', 13, 5),
            ('p3', 15, 2), ('p4', 26, 2),
            ('p5', 18, 6), ('p6', 25, 3),
            ('p7', 20, 4), ('p8', 10, 5),
            ('p9', 15, 4), ('p10', 12, 7),
            ('p11', 19, 3), ('p12', 27, 6),
            ('p13', 16, 4), ('p14', 23, 5),
            ('p15', 14, 2), ('p16', 23, 5),
            ('p17', 12, 7), ('p18', 11, 3),
            ('p19', 16, 5), ('p20', 11, 4)]

def shelving(dairy_items):
    #first: sort the list of tuples based on size: low-to-big
    items = sorted(dairy_items, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)
    #second: iterate the sorted list of tuples.
    #agorithm: retrieve the first 2 elements of the sorted list 
            #then compare those two elements by applying rules/conditions as stated
                #the 'winning' element is placed to 'result' and this element is removed from 'items'. Also 'temp' list is resetted
                #do again untill shelves cannot be added anymore (capacity full and do not exceeds limit) 
    result = []
    total_price = []
    temp_capacity = []
    temp = items[:2]
    while sum(temp_capacity) < capacity:
        #add conditions: (low first) and (if size the same, highest price first)
        if (temp[0][1] == temp[1][1]) and (temp[0][2] > temp[1][2]):
            temp_capacity.append(temp[0][1])
            result.append(temp.pop(0))
            items.pop(0)
            temp.clear()
            temp = items[:2]
            total_price.append(temp[0][2])
        elif ((temp[0][1] == temp[1][1])) and (temp[0][2] < temp[1][2]):
            temp_capacity.append(temp[1][1])
            result.append(temp.pop())
            items.pop()
            temp.clear()
            temp = items[:2]
            print(temp) # -----------NEW LINE ADDED TO DEBUG YOUR CODE
            total_price.append(temp[1][2])
        else:
            temp_capacity.append(temp[0][1])
            result.append(temp.pop(0))
            items.pop(0)
            temp.clear()
            temp = items[:2]
            total_price.append(temp[0][2])
    result = result.append(temp_capacity)
    #return a tuple with three elements: ([list of product ID to be placed in order], total occupied capacity of shelves, total prices)
    return result 
shelving(dairy_items)
```

the result i am getting is:

```
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3), ('p8', 10, 5)]
[('p1', 10, 3)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 55, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 44, in shelving
IndexError: list index out of range
>
```

as you see clearly last index `[('p1', 10, 3)]` has only 1 tuple, hence the `IndexError`